# Density Matrix Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

To my understanding, a state in a quantum system is given by a unitary linear positive trace class operator. I am having some trouble associating such an operator to the following definition of the density matrix given in Landau Lifshitz quantum mechanics. $$\rho(x,x') = \int \Psi(q,x)\Psi^*(q,x')dq$$ where $\Psi(q,x)$ is a wavefunction of a closed system and $\rho(x,x')$ is the function that describes the state of the system where only the $x$ coordinates are considered. Any help or hint to point me in the right direction to explicitly construct an operator which corresponds to such a state would be greatly appreciated. An example of what I am trying to do for the density matrix would be given a unitary vector $\psi$, the associated state is $\frac{(\psi|\cdot)}{(\psi|\psi)}\psi$.

Comment: Do $x$ and $q$ denote sets of coordinates? How is the quantity introduced? As reduced density matrix?

Comment: For all its might, L&L is NOT the best source for this. The most approachable text for this is IMO Blum, Karl. Density matrix theory and applications. Vol. 64. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Comment: $x$ and $q$ were introduced as coordinates of a wavefunction, and $\rho$ was introduced as the definition of the density matrix, and was said to be the most general way to specify a state of a quantum system.

Comment: To be more precise, I am trying to write the expression for $\rho(x,x')$ explicitly as a state in the from $\rho : H\to H$ where $H$ is the underlying Hilbert space.